# I need Firestore Query to check if the object is defined

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

This is the example collection I want to query.

```
{
  name: "example1"
},
{
 name:"example2",
 address: {
  address2: "12 dasl"
 }
},
{
 name:"example3",
 address: {
  address1: "12 dasl"
 }
}
```

EXPECTED RESULT: example2, example3

I tried to use something like

```
db.collection("users").where("address", ">", "")
```

But it doesnt work.

Comment: I think the string comparison might mess it up there. If your addresses are always numbered like that, try `db.collection("users").where("address.address1", ">", "")`

Comment: Can the field be checked for `null`? Looking at the [accepted data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen No My addresses are not numbered always like that.
I edited my object, please check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Firestore can only query fields that are at a known path in each document. Since that isn't the case you can't perform the query you want with your current data model.

From the [Firestore documentation on query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> Cloud Firestore does not support the following types of queries:
>
> ...
>
> Queries of individual array members. You can, however, model and query array-like data using the techniques in [Working with Arrays, Lists, and Sets](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays).

In your case though, I'd consider adding a simple field to each document that marks whether there are any addresses. E.g.:

```
{
  name: "example1",
  hasAddress: false
},
{
 name:"example2",
 hasAddress: true,
 address: {
  address2: "12 dasl"
 }
},
{
 name:"example3",
 hasAddress: true,
 address: {
  address1: "12 dasl"
 }
}
```

Now your query becomes a simple:

```
db.collection("users").where("hasAddress", "==", true)
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like its a solution